# Form still returning true value even there's empty()

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem for doing my form .
When I click the button generate , I'm attempting to redirect to an error page but it stills redirect to the correct page even in the form it's empty.

```
if(isset($_POST['Generate'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['aid'])) {
        $gen_link = "www.correctlink.com";
        $_SESSION['active'] = $aid;
        header("Location: http://$gen_link") ;
    } else {
        header("Location : http://error404.com");
    }
}
```

Even when I click the generate button it stills redirect to www.correctlink.com
I want the user to type something in the form

Form Code:

```
<input type="text" name="aid" id="aid" value="Enter Your Active Here" onfocus=" if (this.value == 'Enter Your Active Here') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='Enter Your Active Here';}  "/><br /><br />

   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Generate" name="Generate" id="Generate"/>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['aid']);` output?

Comment: post your form code also

Comment: @AmalMurali , string(19) "Enter Your Active Here" Enter Your Active Here

Comment: lol..I bet you'll find it really funny if you know why your code is working perfectly

Comment: Try adding `exit;` after each header.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Though a good practice, it won't help in this case as his code is logically working fine

Comment: @aspirin , I know that feeling !! I was like why , what's wrong and then bam . error found

Comment: If the value = Enter Your Active Here . Do you want to count it as a empty field or not? @user3546239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have set a default value of "Enter Your Active Here" in your textbox. If the user simply submits the form without even trying to enter anything in the textbox, the value of `$_POST['aid']` becomes "Enter Your Active Here".

So what do you do? Simple, instead of checking for `empty`, check for

```
if($_POST['aid'] != "Enter Your Active Here" && ! empty(trim($_POST['aid'])))
```

Another solution would be to use a [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) but since that's a HTML5 feature, the compatibility of that across browsers is limited.

EDIT: The second condition is added to make sure the code works in case javascript is disabled on the client machine and the user mischievously tries to submit form by emptying the textbox

Comment: Another problem arise when the field is onfocus and you did not put any value but you click the submit button.Then $_POST['aid'="" .@user3546239

Comment: Not really, there is `onblur` function (which will fire as soon as submit is pressed) to take care of repopulating the field

Comment: But guess when onfocus(by Key Board) and value is still empty at that time you click submit button with mouse.Please see my answer below. @asprin

Comment: Although this works, you need both. !empty and !="Enter your active here". Just incase somebody has JS disabled

Comment: Ok..hadn't considered the non-JS scenario. Good point. Altough, if js is disabled the `onfocus` won't work and we will be back to the value being the default one

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `value` attribute set to something in the form, it will submit that as the value, therefore it won't be empty. Instead of checking if it's empty, check if it equals `Enter Your Active Here`.
If you need a placeholder text, you could use the attribute `placeholder` instead of `value`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST['aid']` is not empty because you set `value` for this as `Enter Your Active Here`

Use something like this

```
<input type="text" name="aid" id="aid" placeholder="Enter Your Active Here" .......
```

OR

```
<label>Enter Your Active Here</label><input type="text" name="aid" id="aid" .....
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 if(!empty($_POST['aid']))
```

by

```
if($_POST['aid']!="" && $_POST['aid']!="Enter Your Active Here")
```

Thanks.